# WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount Inserts record with NULL password?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

I am using basic forms authentication in my MVC 4 project. When I attempt to create a new user using ***CreateUserAndAccount***() method, it creates a record in my profiles table (DB: SQL Server) but the password is defaulted null. I even tried to update the password using WebSecurity.***ChangePassword***() and WebSecurity.***GeneratePasswordResetToken***() + WebSecurity.***ResetPassword***() methods with no luck.

Has anyone had this issue before?

Thanks for your time.
Regards,
Arvind

Comment: I think I got the answer here at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824141/why-is-websecurity-ignoring-my-password

Comment: You can close it then.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for password in profiles table whereas it is stored in webpages_Membership table.

Answer: [Why is WebSecurity ignoring my password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824141/why-is-websecurity-ignoring-my-password)